# Updating last entry of a particular ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `student_log`, and there are multiple records for a single `'rollno'`.

`'sno'` is the auto_increment index of the student_log table.

Suppose I want to update the value of a particular field for the last(most-recent) entry of a particular student(looked up by 'rollno'), how do I do it? My current approach does not work. I am doing this:

```
update student_log set timein=current_timestamp() where rollno='ST001' and 
sno = (select sno from student_log where rollno='ST001' order by sno desc limit 1);
```

Using the subquery, I am trying to retrieve the sno of the most recent record where the student's rollno matches. And I am trying to use it to match sno with the update statement, which isn't working.

I know the syntax is correct, but I think it just means that MySQL does not allow update to use subqueries. Thanks. Ask me if I have missed out any information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE student_log
SET timein=current_timestamp()
WHERE rollno='ST001'
ORDER BY sno DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT**
tested my query, and yes its posible, or what did i miss in OPs table structure

```
mysql> UPDATE student_log
    -> SET timein=current_timestamp()
    -> WHERE rollno='ST001'
    -> ORDER BY sno DESC
    -> LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM student_log;
+-----+--------+---------------------+
| sno | rollno | timein              |
+-----+--------+---------------------+
|   1 | st001  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|   2 | st002  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|   3 | st001  | 2012-07-11 12:05:23 |
+-----+--------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: And that's a nice way to write queries. I mean putting different parts of the query on separate lines. Makes it more readable.

Comment: @QuikTester if you worked with querys longer then 4096 characters, then you got some training on where you like to have rowbreaks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
update 
student_log set timein=current_timestamp() 

where sno in

(

Select sno from 
(
select sno from  student_log where rollno='ST001' order by sno desc limit 1
) tmp
);
```